# Django cross-referencing application templates

Tags: python, django, templates, refactoring

I am refactoring a ton of legacy code based on Django. The project structure is as follows:

```
core_app
app1
app2
...
```

I've encountered the following pattern in various templates, e.g. in **app1**:

```
{% if "app2" in INSTALLED_APPS %}
  {% include app2/path/to/template.html %}
{% endif %}
```

Intuitively this looks very wrong to me. Is there a way to avoid such a tight coupling?

A complex solution that I have in mind is a providers/services mechanism, so that e.g. app2 provides service *X*, app1 calls `{% include_service_X %}`, so that app1 and app2 are unaware of each-other's existence.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the template named `app/app2_inc.html` with the following content:

```
{% if "app2" in INSTALLED_APPS %}
    {% include app2_tpl %}
{% endif %}
```

And the include it with the `with` parameter:

```
{% include "app1/app2_inc.html" with app2_tpl="app2/path/to/template.html" %}
```

As alternative option you can create custom template tag:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def include_app2(context, template_name):
    if 'app2' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        return render_to_string(template_name, context)
    return ''
```

And then call it from your `app1` templates:

```
{% load my_tags %}

{% include_app2 "app2/path/to/template.html" %}
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to silently ignore the case if the template does not exist then change the template tag to:

```
from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def include_if_exist(context, template_name):
    try:
        return render_to_string(template_name, context)
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        return ''
```

So now you can safely include any template from any app.  If this template is not available then template tag will just ignore it:

```
{% load my_tags %}

{% include_if_exist "app2/path/to/template.html" %}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. But it looks like more syntactic sugar for the same `if app installed then include its tempalte` situation. Could you please check the update question and tell if you have more ideas about it?